# Can I call web api from windows phone 7? How?

Tags: windows-phone-7, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My Windows phone 7 app needs to communicate with a site using web api. The site was built using VS2013 Express. Is it possible to make such a call? If yes, can some tell me how can I do it.
I have tested the web api calls using C# console app. However, the same code isn't compiling inside windows phone 7 app.
Her is the code for c# console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SartApiConsoleTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunAsync().Wait(60000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64100/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            // HTTP GET
            response = await client.GetAsync("api/SartData/1");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Success");
                SartData sartData = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SartData>();
                Debug.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", sartData.Id.ToString(), sartData.MRN, sartData.AnswerString);
            }
            else
                Debug.WriteLine("No Success");

            // HTTP POST
            /*
            var gizmo = new Product() { Name = "Gizmo", Price = 100, Category = "Widget" };
            response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", gizmo);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Uri gizmoUrl = response.Headers.Location;

                // HTTP PUT
                gizmo.Price = 80;   // Update price
                response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(gizmoUrl, gizmo);

                // HTTP DELETE
                response = await client.DeleteAsync(gizmoUrl);
            }
            */
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}

class SartData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AnswerString { get; set; }
    public string MRN { get; set; }
}

}
```

When I use the same technique on Windows phone 7, the code doesn't compile. The key word "async" is not being recognized. I couldn't figure out missing assembly, if there is one. Or is there some other way to call web api from Windows phone?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/1.0.165) nuget package to make async/await available.  The phone needs to be updated to 7.5 though.

Comment: NuGet tells me it is already installed though I do not see any dll with similar name in References.
Can the problem be related to target OS version. I have installed SDK 7.8. However, when I create a project, the available target versions are only 7 and 7.1. How can I target other 7.x version?